# Jenkins - How to install a setup of plugins on an agent if I want a slave to do a specific task

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, I'm trying to setup Controller and Agent nodes.

I've two questions here.

1. I want to understand how to install a setup of plugins on an agent?

2  Can I have different agent with different plugins so that I can assign a agent(based on the plugins installed) for a specific build?

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out?

Plugins are installed on master, but jobs steps invoke the plugin on the agent (slave) where run. You can have many agents, but for example if you run a job invoking a windows batch cmd on a linux node, job will just fail.

Use [labels on the nodes](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=753710#Distributedbuilds-Nodelabelsforagents) and your jobs to restrict where a job can run. Search http://plugins.jenkins.io for "label" for some helpful plugins to manage labels. Prefer capability/feature labels instead of tying to hostnames.

Generally, a plugin has a global configuration, and job specific parameters to configure. Not likely to have node by node plugin config but would be plugin specific in any case